# Using python decorator functions from a different module

Tags: python, decorator

I want to use a function from another module as a decorator, but I need it to manipulate the current module's global namespace.

For example, I want to be able to go from this:

```
class SomeClass:
    pass

root = SomeClass
```

to this:

```
from othermodule import decorator

@decorator
class Someclass:
    pass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't that code already work?

Comment: I think he wants the code in decorator to define a root variable in the global scope of the origin class. I'm afraid that is against all python.

Comment: You could have a function that returns the decorator that accepts your globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but try this in `othermodule.py`:

```
import sys
def decorator(cls):
    mod = __import__(cls.__module__)
    mod.root = cls
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks. Actually I ended up using mod = sys.modules[cls.__module__] because the __import__ call only returned the top level module (cls.__module__) was 4 levels deep - ie mod1.mod2.mod3.mod4

Comment: Incidentally, `mod = __import__(cls.__module__, {}, {}, ('*', ))` would return the mod4 module, not the outermost mod1 package

Comment: This is a direct answer (although error-prone for packages and such), but very scary code. Also, it's sort of silly to use `setattr` with string literals. `setattr(foo, 'bar', baz)` is spelled `foo.bar = baz`.

Comment: Yes, the setattr was excessive. I've removed it. The code isn't all that scary: __module__ is a documented attribute of classes. Whether the OP should actually be doing it at all is of course another question.

Answer (score 11):

That already works:

```
from othermodule import decorator

@decorator
class Someclass:
    pass
```

Just put in `othermodule.py`:

```
def decorator(cls):
    #.... do something with cls
    return cls
```

Comment: Yeah I know it works in general, but it's the fact that I want a decorator from the imported module to define a variable in the original module's global scope that causes trouble.

Comment: MyPy, raise an error with that, saying  error: Module "project.decorators" has no attribute "decorator"

Answer (score 6):

Having a decorator modify the global namespace if *any* module, let alone *another* module, is bad and never necessary. Code that mutates far-away globals is difficult to read and maintain. You should definitely consider modifying your design to avoid mutable global state and especially implicit assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a direct decorator, you can have a function that returns a decorator and accepts the globals of your module:

```
def decorator(globals):
    def dec(cls):
        globals.root = cls
        return cls
    return dec

@decorator(globals())
class SomeClass:
    ...
```